# ANTLR - mismatched input error (between token and rule)

Tags: antlr

```html
My grammar:


    SELECT column
    FROM 
                 tableAndAlias       #any_name
                          |  from_model              #from_model_function;
        
       

    from_model: ML.model_function_name'(' MODEL any_name ( (',' (TABLE table_name);

    any_name :
                |   IDENTIFIER
                |   STRING_LITERAL
                |   '(' any_name ')'
                |   NULL


    IDENTIFIER :    
              '"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
            | '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
            | [a-zA-Z_0-9] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
    STRING_LITERAL : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\'' ;


ML:         M L;
MODEL:      M O D E L;
TABLE:      T A B L E;
```

I'm trying to parse:

SELECT column FROM table

the error:
com.cooladata.parser.exceptions.ParseException: Syntax error: in line 4, char 5: unexpected token near 'table'

If I delete the TABLE token it will work fine :

//TABLE:      T A B L E;

also if I change the table name from TABLE TO TABLE**A** ,it will work fine:

SELECT column FROM tablea

how can I use text that can also have a token name?
please advise.

Comment: Can you revise your question such that the example grammar is accepted by ANTLR?  This as several obvious ANTLR syntax errors.  Correcting those errors will make it a bit easier to answer your question (perhaps).

Comment: Please provide a complete grammar. It does not look like a valid Antlr (v4?) grammar: missing the "grammar YourGrammarName;" declaration; "SELECT colum FROM tablealias ..." does not start with a "rule_name :"; rule "from_model" contains unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: I've posted an answer that likely is at the root of the specific recognition problem you're dealing with right now.  But, your example hints at several other midsunderstandgins re: ANTLR grammar syntax.  For example, I'm pretty sure that the ` #any_name` labeled alternative does NOT do what you think it does, and the `|` in the top level rule is probably a significant misunderstanding.  Rule alternative names only apply to top level alternatives.  Syntactically, you have 2 top level alternatives in that rule, but it's highly unlikely that was you actual intention.

Comment: @MikeCargal My grammar is very long and complex, I wrote in question only the relevant part and simplified it as much as possible.
This is not the beginning of grammar, it's a small part :)

Answer (score 0):

Re: “ also if I change the table name from TABLE TO TABLEA ,it will work fine”

and "If I delete the TABLE token it will work fine : //TABLE: T A B L E;"

You need to make sure you have a firm understanding of the Lexing and parsing stages with ANTLR.  The lexer takes a stream of characters and, without any input from the parser, produces a stream of tokens that are used by the parser rules.

It is a good practice to get in the habit of dumping the token stream (`-tokens` option on `grun` command, if you've set that up).  This stream is tokens is what is seen by the parser rules.

In your case, you have a rather well-known issue where the interpretation of the characters 't', 'a', 'b','l', and 'e' can be the `TABLE` keyword in some situations, and a simple identifier in other situations.

Unfortunately (for solving this problem) the Lexer has no concept of the context, and will simply identify this string of characters as a `TABLE` token if you have the `TABLE` rule, or as an `IDENTIFIER`  if you don't have that rule.

You'll have to make a choice as to which way to go, and then handle that in your rules.

Since it's likely that `TABLE` is not the only keyword that could also be a table name.  It's likely that you'll need to accept a "table" `IDENTIFIER` in your rule for recognizing a TABLE definition.  (You'll need a semantic predicate to say, essentially -- accept this `IDENTIFIER` only if it happens to be a case-insensitive "table"

There's a repository of ANTLR grammars [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).  You could select a SQL grammar and look into how others have dealt with this.